# SQL server 2008 merge two tables into one but get duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to combine two tables by SQL server 2008.

table1:

```
 col  col1  col2_a
 yyy  ddd   1589
```

table2:

```
 col  col1  col2_b
 yyy  ddd   6231
```

The tables have same values for col and col1, only col2 are different.
I need to merge them into one table.

```
SELECT a.col , a.col1, a.col2_a, b.col2_b
 FROM table1 as a, table2 as b
 WHERE a.col = b.col AND a.col1 = b.col1
```

But, this give me 4 duplicated rows for each col and col1 combination.

Any help would be appreciated.

I expect :

```
 col  col1  cola  colb
 yyy  ddd   1589  6231
```

Comment: can you please provide sample data?

Comment: Can you show example data and expected output please?

Comment: @user3601704 I can't see your query on your sample data giving any duplicates.

Comment: Your query seems to return the right result

Comment: @codingbiz, this gave me duplicated.

Comment: You may as well try `SELECT DISTINCT a.col, ...`. If that still gives duplicates, we need sample data that does.

Comment: wait, I need to do more check.

Answer (score 0):

If you just plain want to eliminate *exact duplicate rows*, you can simply use `DISTINCT`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.col , a.col1, a.col2_a, b.col2_b
FROM table1 as a
JOIN table2 as b
  ON a.col = b.col AND a.col1 = b.col1
```

If you instead want only *one* value (for example the max one) from table2 even though several rows match, you can select rows from table1 and only the max matching value of b.col2 from table2;

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.col , a.col1, a.col2_a, MAX(b.col2_b) col2_b
FROM table1 as a
JOIN table2 as b
  ON a.col = b.col AND a.col1 = b.col1
GROUP BY a.col, a.col1, a.col2
```